# Ajax success function does not work. checkbox data will not be deleted without hard refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jquery and Ajax method to delete my data using the checkbox. I'm not sure why my data will not delete without a hard refresh. The success function in Ajax doesn't seem working. I do not know what's the problem here. Can someone kindly help me with this problem?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btn_delete').click(function(){
        // if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these products?"))
        // {
            var id=[];

            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
              id[i] = $(this).val();

            });

            if(id.length === 0){
              alert("Please select at least one product");
            }else if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these products?")){
                $.ajax({
                  url:'includes/delete-in-bulk.php',
                  method:'POST',
                  data:{id:id},
                  success:function(){
                    for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
                      $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color','#ccc');
                      $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                  }

                });
            
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }

      });

    });
  </script>
```

**Here are my PHP codes**

```
<tbody id="products">
                  <?php
                  if (!$tot_products) {
                    echo '
                      <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="badge badge-danger">No Products Found</div>
                      </div>
                    ';
                  } else {
                    $i = 1;
                    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                  ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" name="product_id[]" class="delete_products"value="<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">
                        </td>
                    <td>
                      <img src="images/product-main/<?php echo !empty($row['product_photo']) ? $row['product_photo'] : ''; ?>" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $row['product_sku']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo !empty($row['seller_fullname']) ? $row['seller_fullname'] : 'N/A'; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo !empty($row['product_price']) ? $row['product_price'] : 'N/A'; ?>/<?php echo !empty($row['product_unit']) ? $row['product_unit'] : ''; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo !empty($row['product_created']) ? $row['product_created'] : 'N/A'; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo !empty($row['product_stock']) ? $row['product_stock'] : 'N/A'; ?> <?php echo !empty($row['product_unit']) ? $row['product_unit'] : ''; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#productstatus_modal<?php echo $i; ?>" data-sfid="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="modal" title="Click to change the status"><?php echo ($row['product_status'] != 0) ? '<b class="text-success">In Stock</b>' : '<b class="text-danger">Out of Stock</b>'; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a class="text-primary" href="view-product.php?pid=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;" title="View Product">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                      </a>&emsp;
                      <a class="text-danger" href="includes/delete-product.php?pid=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;" title="Delete Product" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this product?');">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                    <!-- The Modal -->
                    <div class="modal hide fade in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="productstatus_modal<?php echo $i; ?>">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <!-- Modal body -->
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="float-right mb-3">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:#ed1c25;">&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-5 col-12">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold mb-3">Product Name: <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?></p>
                                <form action="includes/product-details.php" method="POST">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label><b>Change Product Status</b></label>
                                    <select name="product_status" class="form-control product_status" required>
                                        <option disabled selected>Select Option</option>
                                        <option value="1" <?php if($row['product_status'] == 1) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> >In Stock</option>
                                        <option value="0" <?php if($row['product_status'] == 0) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> >Out of Stock</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label><b>Product Stock <?php echo !empty($row['product_unit']) ? 'in ' .$row['product_unit'] : ''; ?></b></label>
                                      <input type="number" step="any" placeholder="Enter your Stock" name="product_stock" class="form-control textInput" />
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="float-right">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" name="product_id">
                                    <button type="submit" name="chg_prod_status" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                         $i++;
                      }
                    } 
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              
            </div>
          </div>
 <div class="d-flex p-4 justify-content-around">
                    <div class="row">
<button type="button" name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href" value="True" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon-split m-2">
                            <span class="icon text-white-50">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="text">Delete Product</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**here is my delete-in-bulk.php codes**

```
<?php
include '../session.php';

if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 foreach($_POST["id"] as $pid)
 {
  $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = '".$pid."'";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 }
}
?>
```

the codes above are the PHP codes that I added for my checkbox function.
The data can be deleted successfully in the database but it won't be able to delete the data that display on the page without the hard refreshh
please help me resolve this problem. I could not find any problem in the browser console. Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide your php code

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef i've added my php code above

Comment: Long way .. I don't know what is `tot_products` come from .. Also `data:{id:id},` means you pass the ids to php and catch it using `$_POST['id']` which is not found in your php code .. anyway try to directly access `http//mywebsite.com/includes/delete-in-bulk.php` and test the php first then go to another step which is connecting the ajax with php

Comment: Also *I could not find any problem in the browser console* because you need to `console.log` the returned data with success/error callback functions see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217926/3385827)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef i added the delete-in-bulk codes. Can you assist me in resolving this problem?

Comment: I posted an answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

Ok simple ajax/php test

**1st:** The ajax part

```
$.ajax({
     url:'includes/delete-in-bulk.php',
     method:'POST',
     data:{id:id},
     success:function(response){
         console.log(response);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
     }
});
```

You may need to check `includes/delete-in-bulk.php` this path it will be much easier for you to use the full url path `http://mywebsite.com/includes/delete-in-bulk.php`

**2nd:** in php

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST['id']);
?>
```

Now you should see the ids printed out in the console

**3rd:** In php

```
<?php
 $ids = $_POST['id'];
 foreach($ids as $pid){
   echo $pid;
 }
?>
```

Now you should see the ids printed out in the console

**4th:** check the `session.php` path .. start locate it from `delete-in-bulk.php` file maybe its `../../session.php`

**5th:** Add your database code and use

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
 echo 'ok';
}
```

Now you should see the ok in the console

After all of this now everything is ok to do anything in the ajax `success` callback